# TypeError: $scope.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to render the contacts list after retrieving it thru `rdflib.js`. It is loading properly and saving it in the list inside the scope.

But I am not able to render sine the $scope doesn't update, it seems like I am calling `$scope.apply()` in the wrong place. The error occurs because I call it outside angular, but I am deliberately calling it inside the function that is outside angular context (`nowOrWhenFetched`), so not making sense for me. any help?

```
$scope.load = function () {
    //$scope.getContactsList();
    var g = $rdf.graph();
    var f = $rdf.fetcher(g);

    f.nowOrWhenFetched($scope.path + '*',undefined,function(){

    var DC = $rdf.Namespace('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
    var RDF = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
    var LDP = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#');
    //var myOntology = $rdf.Namespace('http://user.pds.org/ontology/'); 
    var VCARD = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#');

    var evs = g.statementsMatching(undefined, RDF('type'), VCARD('Individual'));
    if (evs != undefined) {
        for (var e in evs) {
            var id = evs[e]['subject']['value'];
            var fullname = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('fn'))['object']['value'];
            var email = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasEmail'))['object']['value'];
            var phone = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasTelephone'))['object']['value'];

            var contact = {
                id: id.slice(id.length-1),
                Name: fullname,
                Email: email,
                Phone: phone 
            };

            $scope.contacts.push(contact);
        }

    }

    $scope.apply();

    });

};
```

Comment: You've misspelled it. It should be `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: It look like this is one of the most frequent mistakes which new angular programmers do. And I fall into the same trap, previously.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The function is `$apply()`, with the `$`.

Comment: so it will be $scope.$apply()

Comment: Ehrmeged... I have just wasted 5 hours of my life. But at least you spared me the rest of it :)