# Javascript, angularjs, can a ng-mouseover be inserted dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, onmouseover

This code doesn't apparently work:

```
var run_div = document.createElement('div');
run_div.className = 'whatever';
run_div.textContent = 'whatever';
run_div.setAttribute('ng-mouseover', 'console.log(\'ei\')');
document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild(run_div);
```

I guess it is because `ng-mouseover` has to be there from the beginning so that AngularJS knows (?).
Is this the case? Is there any way to do this?

---

(below: UPDATE 1, UPDATE 2, UPDATE 3)

UPDATE 1:
This code works in a factory, where from the controller I call the factory method sending it the `$scope`:

```
angular.module('whatever').controller('mycontroller', 
['$scope', '$q', '$window', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $q, $window, $timeout) {

$scope.myfunction= function() {
  myfactory.mymethod($scope);
};
```

And the factory calls the `$compile` in its definition:

```
angular.module('whatever').factory('myfactory', 
['$window', '$q', '$compile',
function($window, $q, $compile) {
```

...

```
mymethod = function($scope) {
    var run_div = document.createElement('div');
    run_div.className = 'whatever';
    run_div.textContent = 'whatever';
    run_div.setAttribute('ng-mouseover', 'console.log(\'ei\')');
    document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild(run_div);
}
```

Which doesn't work, and then this throws an error:

```
document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild($compile(run_div)($scope));
document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild($compile(run_div)($scope.new()));
```

or even:

```
var run_div = angular.element(document.createElement('div'));
run_div.addClass('whatever');
run_div.attr('ng-mouseenter', 'console.log(\'ei\'');
document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild($compile(run_div)($scope));
```

where it complains that when appending, the parameter is not a node.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)

---

UPDATE 2:

The following code shows (I think) that when compiling and appending from a factory it doesn't work, but when doing it from a controller, it works (see answer 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/xsaudasp/1/

---

UPDATE 3

I can see that this has to work, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2uk2qe92/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create new $scope instance for your directive and then use $compile service to compile given div with that scope:

```
var directiveScope = $scope.$new();
var compiledDirective = $compile(run_div)(directiveScope);
```

Then you can append it to DOM:

```
angular.element('#my_dir').append(compiledDriective);
```

You must ensure that jQuery is loaded before angular so the jQuery selectors are availible. 
If you don't want to use jQuery you can use jqLite selector instead:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#my_dir')).append(compiledDirective)
```

Here is working jsfiddle of what you need: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/8562/)

Comment: It is not working, it says $scope.new is not a function. I am in a factory function that has received $scope as a variable from the controller

Comment: I'm looking at it, I can see there the functions and variables defined in the controller so I guess it is injected. With the (true) it says the same.

Comment: The message is "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $scope.new is not a function(…)"

Comment: Yes, I've found it now in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307345/typeerror-scope-apply-is-not-a-function , now then the message is the same as the answer above: TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)

Comment: The sentence document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild(run_div); works well, so this has to be discarded

Comment: Same error, it is not a Node, indeed it is a compiled node, but does it matter?

Comment: Not working, I've updated the question with everything I tried following yours and the above suggestions

Comment: I have updated answer. Everything works in included jsfiddle :)

Comment: Yes, that should work, but I then need jQuery, jqLite is not enough. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel Do you know if there is any workaround to use jqLite so that I could avoid using the heavy jQuery?

Comment: I'm trying angular.element(document.getElementById('html_runs')).append(compiled_div);, doesn't throw the error, let's see if this works on my code then ... No, it doesn't work, it doesn't trigger the function

Comment: I was waiting to be able to extrapolate the solution to my code, and now it is working, so THANKS A LOT! :))

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your run_div before insert it inside your DOM:

just use the $compile service this way:

```
document.getElementById('main_div').appendChild($compile(run_div)($scope));
```

you should consider using directives, though: manipulating the DOM inside your controller it's not advised.

### Edit 1:

create a directive this way:

```
.directive('myShinyElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      text: '='
    },
    template '<div class="whatever" ng-mouseover="mouseOver()">{{text}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
       scope.mouseOver = function(){
          console.log('mouseover');
       }
    }
  };
});
```

and use it in your html:

```
<my-shiny-element text="Dataset.analysis[$index].dataset.name"> </my-shiny-element>
```

Comment: It complains that what I am appending is not a Node, I guess it's the same error that I have with the answer below. However, I am not strictly speaking manipulating the DOM, I am creating the DOM and I'm using a factory. Where should I be doing this?

Comment: *Sorry, the "Dataset.ana..." was not meant to be there. In any case, in my case I need to add several elements (like 500), I don't think I should add dynamically them in the form my-shiny-element and then again dynamically to change the text, I believe it must be way more efficient to add the nodes already with the proper text.

Comment: But, the important thing here is that I cannot compile the node, throws the error mentioned in the first comment

Comment: try to change your document.createElement('div') to angular.element(document.createElement('div'));

Comment: Then it complains that setAttribute is not a function

Comment: Because run_div it's a jquery element when you use angular.element: you need to learn the difference between javascript objects and jquery.
You should use .attr() instead of setAttribute, .text() instead of textContent and addClass() instead of className.
See more docs in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element (under *Angular's jqLite*)

Comment: You're completely right. But it's still not working, I create the angular element, run the attr() and addClass() methods, compile it and add it with appendChild, and it keeps complaining in the last one: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…). *(I understand I have to compile as well the angular element)